# Random behaviour of Derivative(D[...]) with option "NonConstants"

Tags: bugs, options, calculus-and-analysis

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 11.1.0**

---

Take the following example code:

```
D[c + h, {{x, y}}, NonConstants -> {c, h}]
D[a + h, {{x, y}}, NonConstants -> {a, h}]
```

Which generates the output:

```
{D[c, x, NonConstants -> {c, h}] + D[h, x, NonConstants -> {c, h}], D[c, y, NonConstants -> {c, h}] + D[h, y, NonConstants -> {c, h}]}
{0,0}
```

Why does this happen? I'm using a clean kernel. This doesn't only happen with the variable name `a`. However I couldn't find a pattern on which names work and which do not.

Mathematica version: 11.0.0

Comment: Both inputs generate `{0,0}` (incorrect) in *Mathematica* 9 or earlier.  In version 10 and later, only `D[c + h, {{x, y}}, NonConstants -> {c, h}]` and `D[i + h, {{x, y}}, NonConstants -> {i, h}]` generate correct results; all others returning `0`.  I'm thinking this is a bug.

Comment: `D[a + b, {{x}}, NonConstants -> {a}]` gives `{0}` in all versions from 8.0 to 11.0.1. Looks like a bug to me, please report it to WRI.

Comment: @jkuczm: I did. I'm waiting for a support response and then I'll update my answer.

Comment: Maybe related: `Dt` is not able to handle gradients (at least not in a documented way), so I get the same wrong result with `Dt[a+h,{{x,y}}]` or `Dt[c+h,{{x,y}}]`. At least in this case both outputs are the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bug fixed in 11.1  Here is screen shot of both systems

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

I've found a partial answer to this. The documentation says:

```
D[f,v1,...,NonConstants->{u1,...}] specifies that every ui implicitly depends on every vj, so that they do not have zero partial derivative.
```

It seems the option is not designed to work with `D[f,{{v1,...}},NonConstants->{u1,...}]`, i.e. gradients.

Still, this is pretty embarrassing considering there is no syntax error for this basic function and the behaviour is pretty random for different variable names. I spend like two days figuring out where my derivatives went missing.

It's probably a bug, but maybe someone has a better answer.

**UPDATE**: The Wolfram support has forwarded this issue to their developers, so it might be fixed in future versions.

**possible workaround**:
Replace

```
D[f,{{v1,...}},NonConstants->{u1,...}]
```

by

```
Table[D[f,{{v1,...}}[[1,i]],NonConstants->{u1,...}], {i,1,Length[{{v1,...}}[[1]]]}]
```

and similar expressions for higher derivatives.